# Wubi on Windows 8 without secure boot?

Tags: 12.04, wubi, windows-8, secure-boot

I have a MacBook Pro.

I've heard rumours that if Windows 8 is going to have this thing called "Secure boot", Wubi cannot work.  At first I plan to install Ubuntu on my mac via Wubi(and windows via bootcamp), but since I can't find my Windows 7 Installation CD, I  installed Windows 8 on my Mac and installed Ubuntu on a VM.

Then suddenly Windows 8 Release Preview was released so I decided to  install over my existing copy of Windows 8 Consumer Preview.

When I went to the Windows 8 Upgrade assistant, it said that the firmware on my Mac doesn't support Secure booting.  I don't even know what it means, but since the Upgrade assistant said that the Mac cannot support secure booting, can I install Wubi successfully?  And what is secure booting anyways?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point about Secure boot isn't supported is an information point - it's not necessary for your UEFI to support Secure Boot or have it enabled on x86 systems. Wubi should run fine.

As for Secure Boot: Secure Boot is a UEFI feature which signs the bootloader and prevents unsigned firmware or software / drivers from running.

Comment: So if I buy a windows 8 computer with Secure booting on it, Wubi should run fine, right?

Comment: @emersonhsieh you'll have to disable secure boot first. After that, yes you should be able to.

Comment: Wubi ran Fine!!

Comment: @emersonhsieh good to hear that!